# Control an element whose id matches with href in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to achieve a simple show/hide content by clicking outside of some links. I can [achieve it with jQuery](https://jsfiddle.net/learner73/9zLyatf6/23/). But, I am struggling to achieve that with vanilla javascript. Basically, I get the id from `a` like this way:

```
const id = e.target.getAttribute('href');
```

Now, I want to work with that `id`, but I can't. So, my problem is in this line:

```
id.classList.remove('hidden');
```

My demo:

```js
const texts = document.querySelectorAll('.content p > span');
const links = document.querySelectorAll('.link-block a');
links.forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('click', e => {
    texts.forEach(text => text.classList.add('hidden'));
    const id = e.target.getAttribute('href');
    //console.log(id);
    id.classList.remove('hidden');
  }); 
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <section class="content">
    <p>
      <span id="content-1">Sample Text for Content 1.</span>
      <span id="content-2" class="hidden">Sample Text for Content 2.</span>
      <span id="content-3" class="hidden">Sample Text for Content 3.</span>
    </p>
  </section>
  <section class="link-block">
    <a href="#content-1">Content 1</a>
    <a href="#content-2">Content 2</a>
    <a href="#content-3">Content 3</a>
  </section>  
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `id` value is a string, not an element.  But that string can be used with `document.querySelector` to find that element.  For example:

```js
const texts = document.querySelectorAll('.content p > span');
const links = document.querySelectorAll('.link-block a');
links.forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('click', e => {
    texts.forEach(text => text.classList.add('hidden'));
    const id = e.target.getAttribute('href');
    //console.log(id);
    document.querySelector(id).classList.remove('hidden');
  }); 
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <section class="content">
    <p>
      <span id="content-1">Sample Text for Content 1.</span>
      <span id="content-2" class="hidden">Sample Text for Content 2.</span>
      <span id="content-3" class="hidden">Sample Text for Content 3.</span>
    </p>
  </section>
  <section class="link-block">
    <a href="#content-1">Content 1</a>
    <a href="#content-2">Content 2</a>
    <a href="#content-3">Content 3</a>
  </section>  
</section>
```